# Load a section of page separately from the rest?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to check the status of a couple of servers and display on a page if they're up or down. Currently, I'm doing this with PHP's `fsockopen()` function. As part of this function, you determine a timeout time. This means that if the servers are down, it'll block for say 2 seconds before moving on. This causes my webpage to wait till the `fsockopen()`s are done before it displays the page.

Is there a way to get these `fsockopen()` functions to run separately from the rendering of the page, and have their results included in after they're determined? It doesn't have to be PHP, I guess.

Comment: Use ajax. Note that it's probably not a good idea to recheck the servers every time for security and efficiency concerns (consider caching the results).

Comment: I believe that this would be done with AJAX, as I tried a similar project a while back, but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Split this into two sub-problems:

1) Create a cron job (or otherwise schedule) a script that will check the server status and save that result somewhere (db, cache, file, post-it, etc). Run it as frequently as you like.

2) Query that result either while rendering the page or via an AJAX call.

Comment: Note: "as frequently as you like" but make sure you're not flooding the server your querying. Don't check more than needed.

Comment: Well - in theory, sure. But practically the smallest cron interval you can set is (every) 1 minute. If one extra request per minute can flood the server, you're doing something wrong :)

Comment: flooding a webserver with valid page request seems like a strange concern. Obviously you dont check your servers up time on a heavy page with lots of queries but on a simple html page or other static content type. You could even just request the headers only

Comment: @HugoDelsing Nobody said something about checking a webserver. He said check "a server", could be anything. This server may think that its being flooded if you send 1 request / minute, which may result in your server getting temporary blocked. Even if this all doesn't apply, checking too much is still a waste of bandwidth on both sides.

Comment: I feel like we're splitting hairs here, but I still have to say: I can not imagine a single scenario where an extra 1 req / minute will make a server (of any kind) "think that it is being flooded", or become blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX. I'd recommend using jQuery's $.ajax function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to call a PHP script which will query a server. You will provide a success function to the ajax call which will be executed when the ajax call has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Create a php page that accepts a variable to know which server to check

```
<?php
$server = isset($_GET['server']) ? $_GET['server'] : '';
$upordown = 'invalid server'; //default incase wrong variable is set

switch ($server) {
  case 'server1':
    //check server 1; EG: $upordown = checkserver('http://www.example.com');
    break;
  case 'server2':
    //check server 2;
    break;
  case 'server3':
    //check server 3;
    break;
}

echo $upordown
?>
```

and then on your show page using jquery:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src='jquery.js'></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $('.serverstatus').each(function() {
      var id = $(this).data('serverid');
      $(this).load('/servercheck.php?server='+id);
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='serverstatus' data-serverid='server1'>loading</div>
  <div class='serverstatus' data-serverid='server2'>loading</div>
  <div class='serverstatus' data-serverid='server3'>loading</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you could add some extra safety like caching and random servernames instead of 1,2,3